# Use of state from useReducer() outside of render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm unable to access state current values outside of the render function. It always return the initial state value

I have a signalR connection and when I receive a message, I want to dispatch an action. The "problem" is: I'm using  the same reducer for two state objects. Therefore, I want to check to which one I should dispatch the action.

Reducer:

```
const processoReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ProcessoIniciado":
      return {...action.payload};
    case "ItemIniciado":
      return { ...state, iniciados: state.iniciados + 1 };
    case "ItemConcluido":
    case "ItemErro":
      var arr = state.mbTiles.slice();
      arr.pop();
      return {
        ...state,
        executados: state.executados + 1,
        iniciados: state.iniciados - 1,
        mbTiles: [action.payload, ...arr]
      };
    default:
      return {...state};
  }
};
```

Component:

```
const mbtiles = props => {
  const [processoSetor, dispatchSetor] = useReducer(processoReducer, {});
  const [processoUsuario, dispatchUsuario] = useReducer(processoReducer, {});
...
useEffect(() => {
...
  hubConnection.on("ItemConcluido", mbtile => {
      updateProcesso(mbtile, "ItemConcluido");
    });
}, []);

const updateProcesso = (mbtileInfo, type) => {
    if (mbtileInfo.processo === processoSetor.id)
      dispatchSetor({ type, payload: mbtileInfo });
    else if (mbtileInfo.processo === processoUsuario.id)
      dispatchUsuario({ type, payload: mbtileInfo });
  };
...
return (
  <>
        <MbTilesContainer processo={processoUsuario} />
        <MbTilesContainer processo={processoSetor} />
  </>
```

The problem is in this line:

```
if (mbtileInfo.processo === processoSetor.id)
```

"processoSetor" is always empty. Even after the "ItemIniciado" action (code omitted) that sets the state before and renders everything fine.

If I comment this line, everything continues to render just fine.

So I was wondering if I have to use a single state and do these checks inside de reducer function, or am I doing something wrong that is preventing me from getting the actual value of the state outside the render function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises due to closure, since your `useEffect` runs only on initial render, when it subscribes to `hubConnection` it refers to the  `updateProcesso` function created on initial render which in the current lexical scope refers to the initial value of reducer state which is an empty object. When the component re-renders this function is recreated whereas the hubConnection callback still refers to the old function which uses to old values of reducer state.

To solve this issue you must pass `processoSetor` and `processoUsuario` in the dependency array to `useEffect` which is second parameter to `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
...
  hubConnection.on("ItemConcluido", mbtile => {
      updateProcesso(mbtile, "ItemConcluido");
    });
}, [processoSetor, processoUsuario]);
```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't quite work, but I was able to see the problem. 
First, the `hubconnection` was instantiated at another closure, because I need to have the original effect on `componnentDidMount` and `unMount`. I resolved it declaring the variable outside the react functional component (not sure if this is a good practice).
Second, the subscriptions on the signalR hub are not overridden. I had to include the unsubscribe method as a return function for the `useEffect()`.